# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'aims'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to connect from my C# application to my MSSQL server.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=167.86.83.190;Database=AIMS;User Id=aims;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;");
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Open();
```

As far as I understand, my settings looks correct:

[image]

This is how databases looks:

[image]

I'm still getting this when trying to open the connection: `Login failed for user 'aims'.`

Please let me know if I can add something to the question to improve it. I'm very unexperienced in this field.

**EDIT:**

Checking logs, I can't see any attempt to login:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

I've enabled logs for logins and restarted the server. After that the connection worked perfectly.

I think that adding the "aims" user and link it to the "AIMS" database didn't make effect until server restarted.

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs and get the true authentication error; if you don't understand that error, then [edit] your question to add that error into it.

Comment: Why are you declaring a local variable named `con` and then using `Database.con` after that? Are you under the mistaken impression that they are the same object?

Comment: I just did a fast modification and forgot to change that as I'm not going to paste the full code here, only the sql part

Comment: @Larnu added a picture showing logs.. I can't see any login attempt

Comment: The IP address is wrong (perhaps to a different instance??), or the password is wrong. Not much more help we can give im afraid.

Comment: `Server=167.86.83.190` is going to connect to the instance that listens on port 1433. You'll want to double check that `VMI341730\SQLEXPRESS` is the correct server and the correct instance. Try actually connecting with `tcp:167.86.83.190` from Management Studio and verifying that `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` gives back what you expect.

Comment: If you just restored the `AIMS` database - like your Logs screen shot suggests - then you need to relink the `aims` login to the `aims` database user.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"I can't see any login attempt"* That suggests you aren't attempting to connect to the instance you *think* you are (unless you have disabled logging of failed logins?).

Comment: I've just checked that login attempts logging is disabled. This is because a malicious freelancer deleted all my server databases and changed settings in the server to make damage. Server is restarting now, will check and update here

Comment: Well, I just enabled logging, restarted server and connection worked. Not sure what made it to work.

Comment: I think the problem was what @AlwaysLearning suggested + restarting the server as I already had the relink done but didn't make effect until restarted

Comment: Side notes: `connection` needs `using` to dispose it. And `if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)` is unnecessary, it's definitely closed